# Hi i need help to solve the Issues in jquery keyup in each function

Tags: jquery, html

I need Jquery script for my calculations Please help me.

I have n number of textbox like class="cad_cons", class="total_cad_cons".

I used Keyup function in this textbox(class="cad_cons").

If I give the values in this textbox(class="cad_cons") that time keyup function should be execute, multiply the values like textbox(class="cad_cons") and textbox(id = "total_item_count") and store in the textbox(class="total_cad_cons")

Here my Codings

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="total_item_count" name="total_item_count">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="cad_cons[]" class="cad_cons"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total_cad_cons[]" class="total_cad_cons"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" name="cad_cons[]" class="cad_cons"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total_cad_cons[]" class="total_cad_cons"></td>
</tr>
```

Jquery Script

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var mult = 0;
 var tot_val = $("#total_item_count").val();
 $('.cad_cons').keyup(function() {
    $('.cad_cons').each(function() {
    var cad_calc =  $(".cad_cons").val(); 
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
      mult += parseFloat(tot_val) * parseFloat(cad_calc); 
   }
    $(".total_cad_cons").val(mult); 
  });
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, how Java solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry. typing mistake

Comment: where is cad_calc defined??

Comment: Now changed my coding. cad_cal value is get from the textbox (class=cad_cons)

Comment: @sathish `var cad_calc = $(this).val();`.

Comment: @abraar Arique returns NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mult = 0;
  var tot_val;
  $('.cad_cons').keyup(function() {
    $('.cad_cons').each(function() {
      tot_val = $("#total_item_count").val();
      var cad_calc = $(this).val();

      if (!isNaN(cad_calc) && cad_calc.length != 0) {
        mult = parseFloat(tot_val) * parseFloat(cad_calc);
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('.total_cad_cons').val(mult);
      } else {
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('.total_cad_cons').val('');
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8ovhtnp/)